# Put var inside jquery :gt()

Tags: jquery, variables

I have a list set with `display:none` and some code to show item 3:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
var item = '1';

$("li:gt(1):lt(1)").show();
```

Is it possible to get the var inside the gt selection? Al I can think of is this

```
$("li:gt('+item+'):lt(1)").show();
```

Doesn't work. 
Can this be done? If not what else can I try?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BSakQ/5/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to delimit the string with the correct quotes. Try this:

```
$("li:gt(" + item + "):lt(1)").show();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use double inverted comma for conacatination beacause you use double inverted comma for selector.

Try this jquery code:

```
$("li:gt("+item+"):lt(1)").show();
```

Comment: That would be a duplicate of Rory's answer. :-)

Comment: I dont know when he post answer I just post my answer I didn't copy.

Comment: @ Jamir: I didn't think you did. But when you post an answer and find that someone has already posted the exact same answer, the right thing to do is to delete your duplicate. (That's what I did, having posted after Rory and before you.)